# bullk rename files by keeping current file name and extension but adding a meaningful keyword prefix (with what we searched)

Tags: bash, shell, file-rename, prefix

I am supposed to carefully (without error or data loss) rename files in a particular directory on linux samba share, which contains hundreds of files (mostly images, docs, pdf guides and ebooks) with different extensions and unique names but not categorised like the example here.

## folder with files (different extension, different case, unique names)

```
a guide to Python.pdf
stay busy with python.epub
ansible tips and tricks.azw3
Ansible secrets.mobi
ANSIBLE for beginners.
_GIT cheat sheet dark (FINAL).png
```

What I would like to achieve is to bulk rename files (keeping same name and extension but add a specific/meaningful prefix to categorise) like below, if possible.

Request - if I can declare a variable like `i="*nsible*"` and then execute the working script which only takes care of files in current directory only... But with name contains Ansible/ansible/ANSIBLE and rename to "`ansible - currentName.currentExt`" will make my life lot better.

Please note that I would like to use a variable each time for e.g., "python" and deal with all python files in one go. Then next time I would like to try "ansible" files/images execution...

## Targeting below result that I would  like to achieve.

```
python - a guide to python.pdf
python - busy with python.epub
ansible - ansible tips and tricks.azw3
ansible - Ansible secrets.mobi
ansible - ANSIBLE for beginners.jpeg
git - GIT cheat sheet dark (FINAL).png # prefixed "git - " and removed the hyphen
```

with all my best efforts and finding the solution for the same, i havent been successful yet. So would like someone to guide me correctly.

Expected result shared above

I tried below it works like minimal

```
for file in *nsible*; do mv "$file" "ansible - $file"; done;
```

Comment: What about original filenames like `ansible - a guide for python programmers.epub`, or `extending git with python.pdf` or `middle digit.jpg`?

Comment: *"I tried below..."* . Yes, that is the essence of what you must do for each file-type  you want to process. If you replace your target filenamess with a variable, and then you put the targs in a list, you can do `list=(a b c) ; for targ in "${list[@]}" ; do for file in *$targ* ; do ... done ; done`.  But you'll find you need to expand the innermost loop to process all of the exceptions you have listed, i.e. ignoring case and *"prefixed "git - " and removed the hyphen"*. We're can't write it for you. Update your Q with you best guess and we'll help you improve your understanding. Good luck.

Comment: Get it to work for the basic cases, without the exception processing, and then it will be easier to work from known code and add one "feature" at a time. Good luck.

Comment: Would also suggest a `find /path -type f -iname "*${yourvar}*" | while read -r fname; do #yourstuff; done` and let `find` perform a case-insensitive find of the matching filenames. If you need more control than globbing, `find` will also select files by REGEX. You can also write a short helper-script and do it all with `find` using the `... -exec ./helper-script.sh '{}'  \;` passing the filename to modify as the first argument to your helper script.

Comment: Appreciate all the help. I envy you :) and wish to be like you... hope one day. I could tell you i didn't get a chance to sit on computer else i'd have definitely tested it, Tomorrow then.

 Please see below, 
`for file in *ocker*; do mv "$file" "docker - $file"; done;`

with find command a week back i lost more than 1.5 TB of data...barely survived. But this time i think the quick solution would work in my case, i know it has it's flaws. I would try to use your scripts. Also hope many others will benefit with your answers. Thank you for now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small script I built for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Setup
rm -fr files
mkdir files
cd files
touch "a guide to Python.pdf"
touch "stay busy with python.epub"
touch "ansible tips and tricks.azw3"
touch "Ansible secrets.mobi"
touch "ANSIBLE for beginners."
touch "_GIT cheat sheet dark (FINAL).png"
cd ..

################################################################################

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 DIR"
    echo "DIR: directory where the files reside"
    exit 1
else
    thedir="$1"
    if [[ ! -d "$thedir" ]]
    then
        echo "ERROR: directory >>$thedir<< does not exist."
        exit 2
    fi
fi

tags="python ansible git"

for t in ${tags}
do
    echo "tag=$t"

    find "$thedir" -type f -iname "*$t*" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
    do
        # here find returns the path as well, so extract the filename only
        # and remove all "_" at the same time
        filename=$(basename "$file" | tr -d '_')

        mv -v "$file" "$thedir"/"$t - $filename"
    done
    echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------"
done
```

Using it:

- to call the script: `./script.bash files`
- where "files" is the directory where the files reside.  Note that the setup code should be removed when you are ready to use it on your real files, this was just for my tests.
- a `for` loop is used to process each tag in succession.  I define tags as what you are looking for.  Here `tags="python ansible git"`
- then a `find` is run into the directory, with the desired tag.
- NOTE: the `find` will traverse sub-directories.  If you do not want that, you can replace the `find` with this: `find "$thedir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*$t*" -print0`
- the `print0` option is for the `read` in the `while` loop.  Full details here: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001
- `mv -v ...` the -v option lets you know what was done by `mv`, for tracking purposes.
- `tr -d '_'`: this is used to remove the `_` from your filenames.  It will remove **all** `_` in **all** filenames!
- instead of renaming files, you could create sub-directories, one per tag, and move the files there.  Just a thought.

---

The output when I run this is:

```
$ ./so.bash  files
tag=python
renamed 'files/stay busy with python.epub' -> 'files/python - stay busy with python.epub'
renamed 'files/a guide to Python.pdf' -> 'files/python - a guide to Python.pdf'
---------------------------------------------------------------------
tag=ansible
renamed 'files/Ansible secrets.mobi' -> 'files/ansible - Ansible secrets.mobi'
renamed 'files/ansible tips and tricks.azw3' -> 'files/ansible - ansible tips and tricks.azw3'
renamed 'files/ANSIBLE for beginners.' -> 'files/ansible - ANSIBLE for beginners.'
---------------------------------------------------------------------
tag=git
renamed 'files/_GIT cheat sheet dark (FINAL).png' -> 'files/git - GIT cheat sheet dark (FINAL).png'
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**Disclaimer** as you mention loosing files in the comments above, this script is provided to you *as-is*, I cannot be held responsible for data loss.  Backups are a must!

Comment: If it meets your requirements, you can accept the answer with the check mark on the left of the answer.

Comment: seem like maybe i'm doing something wrong

Comment: root@omv-dell:/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-31d9a024-4104-4abd-924f-9b02ce6e355b# ./second_script.sh
Usage: ./second_script.sh DIR
DIR: directory where the files reside

Note - i splitted your shared code to 2 scripts. first one create dummy files and dir(files) for the same
When i execute the second script it's throwing this error (pasted above)

Comment: You must specify the directory you want the script to process.  So call it like that: `./second_script.sh THE_DIRECTORY_WHERE_FILES_ARE`